# Can a third query execute in the middle of two queries inside the same db.any() call?

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, pg-promise

If I have the following code, executed in the middle of a request:

```
db.any('SET search_path TO user001; SELECT * FROM messages')
```

Could a second request execute a query in between the SET and the SELECT of the first query?
For example:

- First request arrives
- `SET search_path TO user001` (1st)
- Second request arrives
- `SET search_path TO user002` (2nd)
- `SELECT * FROM messages` (1st)
- `SELECT * FROM messages` (2nd)

Also what's a good way of defining the search_path at run time? I thought of using db.task() but that would limit the number of requests per second to around 100, right?

Comment: Please clarify: a) by "second request' you mean: any other query to postgresql? Only from  your app or from other clients connected to PostgreSQL instance? b) if you mean only your app: do you open multiple concurrent  sessions to db server?

Comment: @AlexYu a) any other query to postgresql generated by a second HTTP request b) No, I'm using the same "db" object to do my queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could a second request execute a query in between the SET and the SELECT of the first query?

No, such a query is processed as one, what's known as atomic operation.

> Also what's a good way of defining the search_path at run time?

Within `pg-promise`, initialization option [schema](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/module-pg-promise.html) does that. It sets the schema(s) automatically for every fresh connection.

However, if you need to keep changing the current schema for every single request, i.e. if you actually have a separate database schema for every user, then it won't work, and you will need to use that approach you tried, i.e. prepend schema-changing query to every query.

However again, there is no point in doing it for each query while handling one request, you need to do it only once, when you start handling the request. And this is why automatic tasks/transactions are best suited for that. In fact, you can use event [extend](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:extend) to add your own custom task/transaction that would execute schema change in the beginning.

> I thought of using db.task() but that would limit the number of requests per second to around 100, right?

No, where did you find such information? :) Tasks do not add any such limitation.

Comment: I thought they did, doesn't a task reserve a connection until the callback exits? Imagine I store the DB context using AsyncLocalStorage and pull it on every file I do DB operations, only releasing it when the response is sent back to the user. Won't this keep the connection open until everything is done? And looking at how max_connections is defaulted to 100, I thought that 100 simultaneous requests would use all the available connections from the pool

Comment: Why would you want to release the connection before the task completes? The task represents your request handler, so you use the connection till finished, and then it will be released automatically.